# Making an API with Lua in ComputerCraft

Tags: computercraft

I'm trying to make an API that encrypts strings in ComputerCraft. However, i'm not sure how I would make have the encryption function return the encrypted text. How would I have a function return something?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to make a function in lua is

```lua
function encrypt(text)
[you encrypting algorithm here]
return encrypteddata
end
```

Here are the documentation for the Strings in Lua (you'll need it to encrypt your text): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_strings.htm